# insert All Listbox items into a List

Tags: c#, list

Are there a way to export the items from an Listbox into a List in c#?
i have Listbox1 that Contain some string items and I have This list:

```
public List<String> MyList = new List<String>();
```

how to add this items to Mylist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a casting like this:

```
public List<String> MyList = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().ToList();
```

This way, to change the ListBox ObjectCollection to list of string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AddRange` method:

If you are sure that all elements in `Listbox1` are strings:

```
MyList.AddRange(ListBox1.Items.Cast<string>());
```

if not:

```
MyList.AddRange(ListBox1.Items.OfType<string>());
```